# Extract all JSON keys and values as map

Tags: go

i want to get all keys and values of json fields as type map[string][]string. The objects with same keys, should be in same map field.

I can convert JSON to map[string]interface{} now with this function, but it doesn't meet my needs.

```
func jsonToMap(data []byte) map[string]interface{} {
    x := map[string]interface{}
    json.Unmarshal(data, &x)

    return x
}
```

Sample json:

```
  {
  "data": {
    "name": "John",
    "age": 30
  },
  "items": [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ],
  "data2": {
    "name": "Johns",
    "age": {
      "test": [
        1,
        2,
        3,
        {
          "test2": "123"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Expected result:

```
map[string][]string
map["data"][]string{""}
map["name"][]string{"John", "Johns"}
map["age"][]string{"30",""}
map["items"][]string{"1","2","3"}
map["test"][]string{"1","2","3"}
map["test2"][]string{"123"}
```

Comment: OK, now we know what you want. Go ahead and do it. Got stuck or have some issues? That's the time to post your code and issues here, and we can help with that. Aim for a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks, i have updated. Is it ok ?

Comment: You need to iterate over the map entries, recursively and collect the values. Your expected output also requires converting some values to string (e.g. `1` => `"1"`), and also omitting some (composite) values, such as `"data"` (more precisely using the empty string for them).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is using `recursive function`.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)

Here is a simple example:
https://gobyexample.com/recursion

The following code can do what you want:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    JSONStr := `{
        "data": {"name": "John", "age": 30},
        "items": [1, 2, 3],
        "data2": {
            "name": "Johns",
            "age": {"test": [1, 2, 3, {"test2": "123"}]}
        }
    }`

    var JSON map[string]interface{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(JSONStr), &JSON)

    neededOutput := jsonToMap(JSON)
    fmt.Println(neededOutput)
}

func jsonToMap(data map[string]interface{}) map[string][]string {
    // final output
    out := make(map[string][]string)

    // check all keys in data
    for key, value := range data {
        // check if key not exist in out variable, add it
        if _, ok := out[key]; !ok {
            out[key] = []string{}
        }

        if valueA, ok := value.(map[string]interface{}); ok { // if value is map
            out[key] = append(out[key], "")
            for keyB, valueB := range jsonToMap(valueA) {
                if _, ok := out[keyB]; !ok {
                    out[keyB] = []string{}
                }
                out[keyB] = append(out[keyB], valueB...)
            }
        } else if valueA, ok := value.([]interface{}); ok { // if value is array
            for _, valueB := range valueA {
                if valueC, ok := valueB.(map[string]interface{}); ok {
                    for keyD, valueD := range jsonToMap(valueC) {
                        if _, ok := out[keyD]; !ok {
                            out[keyD] = []string{}
                        }
                        out[keyD] = append(out[keyD], valueD...)
                    }
                } else {
                    out[key] = append(out[key], fmt.Sprintf("%v", valueB))
                }
            }
        } else { // if string and numbers and other ...
            out[key] = append(out[key], fmt.Sprintf("%v", value))
        }
    }
    return out
}
```

Output:

```
map[age:[30 ] data:[] data2:[] items:[1 2 3] name:[John Johns] test:[1 2 3] test2:[123]]
```

Comment: Really impressive. Thanks!